# Unable to change delegate on NSSplitView

Tags: xcode, swift, interface-builder, nssplitview, nssplitviewcontroller

I have a storyboard that contains a main window (with a corresponding `MainWindowController` class), and a main view (an `NSSplitViewController`, with corresponding `MainViewController` class).  For certain functionality I am attempting to set the delegate of the `NSSplitView` contained in the view to the `MainWindowController` class.

Without any IB linkage, the `NSSplitView` delegate is already set to the `MainViewController` at application launch. I am able to get a reference to the `MainWindowController`, but when I attempt to set the delegate to the window controller (which does implement `NSSplitViewDelegate`), I am getting the following:

```
*** Assertion failure in -[NSSplitView setDelegate:], /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/AppKit/AppKit-1404.34/AppKit.subproj/NSSplitView.m:600
```

This also happens if I attempt to set the delegate to `nil`.

Does anyone know why this might be so, whether there are restrictions on setting delegates, and if there is a way to use IB to set the delegate of an item in a view to another Controller?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a reference for this but I'm pretty sure the split view and the split view controller aren't meant to be separated. Fortunately, `NSSplitViewController` mirrors the delegate methods, giving you a chance to intervene. There should therefore be no reason to change the split view's delegate.

Comment: Yes, the penny drops.  After all, what is the point of using an NSSplitViewController if the split view doesn't use it?  In the end, it was a matter of implementing the protocol calls within the View Controller and the Window Controller and then calling a shared method to handle them. (The scenario was wanting a split view in the title bar to track the split view in the main view).  Thanks for the help.